Duplicate nodes in batch
I'm trying to write a module to duplicate a series of nodes and to make sure there is no timeout I want to use the Batch Api for this.
This is what I have at this moment in src/Controller/NodeCloneController.php:
namespace Drupal\book_clone\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Class CloneNodesController.
 */
class CloneNodesController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Clone nodes.
   */
  public function cloneNodes() {
    $nids = [55,92,86];
    $this->book_clone_clone_multiple_nodes($nids);

    $this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Nodes are being cloned.'));

    return $this->redirect('system.admin_content');
  }

  function book_clone_clone_multiple_nodes(array $nids) {
    $operations = [];
    foreach ($nids as $nid) {
      $operations[] = [
        [
          $this->book_clone_clone_node($nid),
          [],
        ],
      ];
    }

    $batch = [
      'title' => t('Cloning'),
      'operations' => $operations,
      'finished' => $this->book_clone_batch_finished(),
    ];
    
    batch_set($batch);
  }

  function book_clone_clone_node($nid) {
    $node = Node::load($nid);
    if ($node) {
      $cloned_node = $node->createDuplicate();
      $cloned_node->save();
    }
  }

  function book_clone_batch_finished() {
      $message = t('Finished');
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($message);
  }
}

The function cloneNodes is called by going to a specific admin path via a routing file:
book_clone.clone_nodes:
  path: '/admin/content/clone'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\book_clone\Controller\CloneNodesController::cloneNodes'
    _title: 'Clone Nodes'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

Cloning works with this code but I don't see the batch page and progressbar. So I don't know if the batch is working and I want to show this page for my users to get proper feedback. First time using Batch so I think i'm missing something here. What am I doing wrong?

You are calling the class methods when filling the array but you have to use a callback format so that they are called when the batch runs:
$batch = [
  'title' => $this->t('My batch'),
  'operations' => [
    [[$this, 'batchProcess'], [$nid]],
  ],
  'finished' => [$this, 'batchFinished'],
];

batch_set($batch);

These callbacks run in an instantiated object of your class. Most usage for the batch API is static, though. I think to avoid problems with caching of serialized objects. Then replace $this with static::class and make the methods static:
public static function batchProcess($nid) {

public static function batchFinished($success, $results, $operations) {


As you're in a controller you'll need to manually trigger the batch to run. Only in the form API will it auto trigger. Something like this should work:
$goto = '/';
$batch = batch_get();
if (!empty($batch)) {
  return batch_process($goto);
}

You need to do the check to make sure the batch isn't empty otherwise you'll get an error
